# Bootstrap select is not showing

Tags: css, angularjs, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to use bootstrap-select with my angular project but it does not appear at all.

My dependencies after installing the bootstrap-select package with bower:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">
```

And for the js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

This is the only rule that is applied to the select item from the bootstrap-select css stylesheet.

> select.bs-select-hidden, select.selectpicker {
>       display: none !important;
>   }

Is some of the other packages breaking it?

Thank you

My versions angular:1.6.2, bootstrap:3.3.7, bootstrap-select:1.12.2

Comment: What does the html look like?  Your css is setting the display to none.  I would expect it to not display....

Comment: The html is the default example from bootstrap-select 
`<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>`
The css is not mine, it is the select-bootstrap css and the only rule that is applied to the html is the one with display none. A link to the [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, what i did was:

1) Download Bootstrap-select from [SilvioMoreto Git](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select);
2) Copy the bootstrap-select.js from bootstrap-select/js;
3) Paste the file in your project javascripts directory;
4) Link path to the file in your project header;

It worked for me, hope it helps!